# Best way to create a table for data in R?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, r, csv, xtable

**Main question:** What is the best way to create a table in a LaTeX document for data from R?

At first glance, two possibilities seem conceivable:

1. Let R create the table and "paste" it into the LaTeX document
2. Export the data to a .csv file and create the table in LaTeX

**Subquestion I:** Are there "other" possibilities?

---

### Ad possibility 1

It seems like the R package [xtable](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html) is used by "some" users to achieve something like this.

For sure, it would be convenient, if the generated LaTeX code would be stored in a file `my_table.tex` and one could use `\input{my_table.tex}` or similar in LaTeX.

**Subquestion II:** Any hints on that approach?

---

### Ad possibility 2

There seem to be latex packages like [csvsimple](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple), [pgfplotstable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) and maybe others

**Subquestion III:** Are there other (recommended) packages?

**Subquestion IV:** Any hints on that approach?

---

**Subquestion V:** Which approach do you recommend?

Comment: I am not sure if this is _the best_ way but [kableExtra](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/) can produce a code for decent looking LaTeX tables. On the site, click [for LaTeX](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) for more info.

Comment: `xtable` can use a `file=...` argument to save the generated code as a file.  Or you can embed the R code directly into your LaTeX document and knit the two together with `knitr`. See the answers here: [How can I use a table generated by R in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/25575). The accepted answer is a bit old; there are definitely other options mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Personally I don't think storing R output as CSV and then using one of the LaTeX table packages is the right way to go. It makes more sense to generate the table with R directly.